# "Multi-instance" kernel module and parameterization

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, alsa

I'm developing a kernel module which should handle multiple instances of itself. It should open multiple virtual soundcards. Such a virtual soundcard would just stream audio packets via UDP packets to a specific IP address.

In my case whenever the kernel module is modprobe'd for the first time it will create one instance of virtual soundcard (an ALSA compliant device) exposing a set of ALSA nodes - /dev/snd/controlC0, /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p and /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c. On a second "load request" it would expose another set of ALSA nodes - /dev/snd/controlC1, /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p and /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c.

My question is:

1. It is not possible to modprobe one and a same kernel module multiple times, right? (I know it is not, just confirm, please)
2. Once kernel module is loaded how can I create second (third, etc...) instance of it? How to pass a parameter to it to create another instance and distinguish each other? Can I use SYSFS?
3. If I can use SYSFS how can I have complex parameterization?

For example:

If I want to set a parameter virt_soundcard_name="room1", virt_soundcard_ip="192.168.1.105", virt_soundcard_number_of_channels="8" what is the easiest way? Can I pass a file or a line of a file with that configuration to the kernel module through SYSFS or whatever..?

Comment: Load once, use multiple times. Yes, sysfs would help. Of course you may choose another IPC for your module.

Comment: May be I'm going to use similar approach as in gpio-keys:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/gpio_keys.c

It exposes some attributes under /sys/devices/platform/gpio-keys/. So it is similar to what I need.
What is your opinion? Is there any more "user-friendly" solution?

Comment: Forgot to clarify - I need it as file-based approach because I'm going to use Python/Bash to configure the kernel module. I won't have middleware in the userspace as libraries in C, etc.

Comment: Any design is good if you understand pros and cons.

Comment: You could implement a control device with an interface that allows virtual soundcards to be created and destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable. So you mean to customize the backend behind /dev/snd/controlC0 for example, right?